# How can I disable the autocomplete property of a NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

When the completions dropdown list of my NSTextView appears, the text is filled in in the NSTextView. How could I avoid that, so that the text view remains empty, or include only the text I've typed?

I can't find the autocomplete property in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could override `-insertCompletion:forPartialWordRange:movement:isFinal:` in a subclass. If the `isFinal` flag is `NO`, do nothing. If it's `YES`, call through to `super`.